# Conditional generic to check if type extends readonly property on function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

My goal below is to type `p` to be `{ size: number | undefined, shape: string }`, I am having an issue creating a condition around the readonly `required` property that the `required` and `optional` functions have attached to them. I've tried a couple of different combinations but the main line that is not doing the detection is:

```
ReturnType<IPayloadObjectTypeMap[key]> extends Readonly<{ required: false }>
```

> Note: I have added a  `| true` and  `| false` to the last condition as a way to test the outcome of the condition, and I am unable to have it be true, in the final code, I'd expect the first extend to be a union of `undefined` and the second to not have a union, just the first type.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJwKYEcQzQE0QHgDElUAPKVMHAZ0QBVkBDMa4OZAWwAlmcAbVMgB8iABTAwALkTEAlIgDeAKEQpUUEMiQB5AEYArVNAB0jatRgBzMOLAAaRWszZUOaVGQhUiAL6IziBAI1FCySj5KSqCQsAiIcAAOsWCMfATEiGQUVLQMzKzs3LwCwmIS0nKKKmoaWoh6hiZmFta2DgpOWLjSwKnU3n4BQSyh4ZFQAJ4J3nksbJw8VCX4AJJgCSBQiAC8-mATDtqbG1u7zBMiu6Iw65vSayfy2yJHUCdKk9P0THOFi-yCACi5EoOFcq1upz2B3qx02O2hl2++XmRSWgghJ0OcKgIgAZI40M5uohdHA4AJmL4PlNvAAFRgTPhwRg4BpGKB0WkAWUYCQRHQA2gBrVATaQhZA3SwAXWkswKC2KQJBVFc1M+3mBHkY0AZTJZOFW+uZrPZ0C5015-KyoNoJsN5s5PL5SOUqhFYsQN0QoomcGAiBWDrNBg5ltQ1rlQZDbLDFpdCU9ExlmVVNGRvyV6OQiAA-IhqgAldSaMAR42M01xxrOq185MykS2nKIEushB8Cb4DpErquHp9AZCaqqVQFku1cu0ysG0O1iPWxsiAA+iA8XlHY+kk7LFeDVcd8brkYbfqbiDXvT4-Wq0jAqAAboIxkphiFEPzdu7EBYAF6oNIiTJKkoiPjsIgJIwyD9GsUBgbIsh2NU1AABZ8oBnQuDgYEQYg4EANSIAARMRYQRDSXyWAi2pMHqh6svgmoBp+I4APRsaoAB6eZKBxv6oXAIB8HgujeB0-6YWAIAcGJuZruAYLADcrgOGhGESh40q+IgQA)

```
function required <Fn extends TransformHandler> (fn: Fn) {
  return Object.assign(fn, { required: true } as const)
}

function optional <Fn extends TransformHandler> (fn: Fn) {
  return Object.assign(fn, { required: false } as const)
}

type TransformHandler<Input = any, Output = any> = (input: Input) => Output
type TransformHandlerExtended<Input = any, Output = any> = TransformHandler<Input, Output> & { required: boolean }
type PayloadObjectTypeMap = { [key: string]: TransformHandlerExtended }
type ExtractPayload<IPayloadObjectTypeMap extends PayloadObjectTypeMap> = {
  [key in keyof IPayloadObjectTypeMap]: IPayloadObjectTypeMap[key] extends TransformHandler ? 
  ReturnType<IPayloadObjectTypeMap[key]> extends Readonly<{ required: false }>
      ? ReturnType<IPayloadObjectTypeMap[key]> | true
      : ReturnType<IPayloadObjectTypeMap[key]> | false
  : never
}

const p = {
  size: optional(v => parseInt(v)),
  shape: required(v => v + "")
}

type g = ExtractPayload<typeof p>
//  ^?
// should be { size: number | undefined, shape: string }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was checking the return type and not the function type itself

```
function required <Fn extends TransformHandler> (fn: Fn) {
  return Object.assign(fn, { required: true } as const)
}

function optional <Fn extends TransformHandler> (fn: Fn) {
  return Object.assign(fn, { required: false } as const)
}

type TransformHandler<Input = any, Output = any> = (input: Input) => Output
type TransformHandlerExtended<Input = any, Output = any, Required = boolean> =
  TransformHandler<Input, Output> &
  Readonly<{ required: Required }>
type PayloadObjectTypeMap = { [key: string]: TransformHandlerExtended }
type ExtractPayload<IPayloadObjectTypeMap extends PayloadObjectTypeMap> = {
  [key in keyof IPayloadObjectTypeMap]: IPayloadObjectTypeMap[key] extends TransformHandler ?
    IPayloadObjectTypeMap[key] extends Readonly<{ required: false }>
      ? ReturnType<IPayloadObjectTypeMap[key]> | undefined
      : ReturnType<IPayloadObjectTypeMap[key]>
  : never
}

const p = {
  size: optional(v => parseInt(v)),
  shape: required(v => v + "")
}

type g = ExtractPayload<typeof p>
```